# how to change firefox proxy settings using xpcom

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I have a proxy server running on localhost (127.0.0.1) and i have **grown tired** of having to train users on how to switch proxies in firefox to bypass blocked websites.
 I decided to write an addon. I wonder how to use **xpcom** to tell firefox to use a certain proxy eg
for http, use 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
Examples on the internet are scarce.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proxy settings are stored in the [preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences). You probably want to change `network.proxy.type`, `network.proxy.http` and `network.proxy.http_port` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Networking_Preferences#Proxy)). Like this:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 1);
Services.prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.http", "127.0.0.1");
Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);
```

If you need to determine the proxy dynamically for each URL, you can use the functionality provider by [`nsIProtocolProxyService` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProtocolProxyService) - it allows you to define a "proxy filter". Something like this should work:

```js
var pps = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/protocol-proxy-service;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProtocolProxyService);

// Create the proxy info object in advance to avoid creating one every time
var myProxyInfo = pps.newProxyInfo("http", "127.0.0.1", 8080, 0, -1, 0);

var filter = {
  applyFilter: function(pps, uri, proxy)
  {
    if (uri.spec == ...)
      return myProxyInfo;
    else
      return proxy;
  }
};
pps.registerFilter(filter, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this somewhere. But it has a problem of changing the proxy globally, yet i prefer it does it per page

Comment: @DrDeo: It's generally a good idea to put this kind of thing into the question ;) I think that the only way is changing the global proxy settings when the page starts loading, from what I remember there is no proxy setting for a load group. But if the proxy selection logic is fixed then you could put it into a PAC file.

Comment: @DrDeo: Looked into this, apparently I was wrong - there is a way to set the proxy dynamically for each URL. Edited my answer.